Is $\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\cdots$ really $\{\emptyset\}$
Our lecturer gave us the following example in limit inferior and superior:

$(A_n)=[n,+\infty)\forall n\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

\begin{align}
A_1 &= [1,\infty),\,A_2=[2,\infty),\,A_3=[3,\infty),\ldots \\
                \varlimsup(A_n) &= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcup_{j=n}^\infty A_j\right) \\
                &= (A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots)\cap(A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots)\cap(A_3\cup A_4\cup\cdots)\cap\cdots \\
                &= [1,\infty)\cap[2,\infty)\cap[3,\infty)\cap\cdots \\
                &= \{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset \\ \\
                \varliminf(A_n) &= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{j=n}^\infty A_j\right) \\
                &= (A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots)\cup(A_2\cap A_3\cap\cdots)\cup(A_3\cap A_4\cap\cdots)\cup\cdots \\
                &= \emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\cdots \\
                &= \{\emptyset\}
\end{align}
Basically he insists that the answers are $\{\emptyset\}$ which makes no sense. I don't agree with this. Aren't the answers supposed to be:
\begin{align}
\varlimsup(A_n) &= [1,\infty)\cap[2,\infty)\cap[3,\infty)\cap\cdots \\
&= \emptyset \\
\varliminf(A_n) &= \emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\cdots \\
&= \emptyset
\end{align}

Please correct this if I am wrong, but is $\phi$ not already a set, so writing ${\phi}$ doesn't make sense in the first place...

You and you lecturer are both wrong.

@RedFive Yes, $\emptyset$ is a set (with zero elements), while ${\emptyset}$ is a different set (with one element).

In the end of your post, you probably meant $\emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \ldots$?

Don't use spoilers in a question.

The spoiler was just me venting. But I got it

@Aig yeah I did mean that. I mixed up the thing

You are right and your instructor is wrong. Be sure to approach them politely when you ask for clarification. (Please [edit] the question to clean it up.)

Thanks for the tip!

There's no way to produce ${\emptyset}$ through unions and intersections of $X_n$ sets if $\emptyset\not\in X_n$ for any $n$. Which is your case. It's a weird claim.
